# Почему на breakpoint bootstrap едет верстка?

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Почему на breakpoint bootstrap едет верстка?
Верстка едет именно на breakpoint: 1200, 992, 768, 576.
А вот 
1201 +, 
991-1199, 
769-993,
575-767, 
320-577 все отображает нормально
В чем причина?
Медиа-запросы прописаны по breakpoint'ам

Comment: Мне не лень, я искренне не понимаю почему так? П.С. я новичок, не кидайте тапками

Comment: viewport подключен, toggle device toolbar использую, в инспектор смотрю, но не понимаю почему именно 1 px оно скачет, посмотрите пожалуйста, может заметите что опытным взглядом?! (http://test.aleksandernitchenko.ru)

Comment: может потому что бутстрап использует `@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  }` а я использую`@media (max-width: 1200px) {` и дальше по всем брейкпоинтам также

Comment: Не глядя на сайт, предположу, что у вас интервалы перекрываются. То есть должно быть 768-991,992-1200 и т.д. Но не 768-992,992-1200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была при указании в файле стилей
`@media (max-width: 576px)` вместо `@media (max-width: 575.98px)` как указано в бутстрапе и дальше по всем breakpoint так же, всем спасибо за подсказки